# Help me to query this two tables properly

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Here is my mySQL query which I used to get the details from three tables.

```
    SELECT `pg`.`id`, 
ref, business_name, `usr`.`full_name`, 
date, `pmt`.`amount`, `pg`.`status` 
    FROM kv_ad_orders AS `pg` 
    LEFT JOIN kv_users AS `usr` 
           ON `pg`.`sales_rep_id` = `usr`.`ID` 
    RIGHT JOIN kv_payments AS `pmt` 
            ON `pg`.`ref` = `pmt`. `transId`
```

here it shows only the `kv_payments` table entries only. Not the whole results. I want to  display all the selected columns.

If I make it as left join table, than its showing other results except the amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the rows that have Orders and Payments but maybe don't have user go for the Inner Join/Left join

```
SELECT `pg`.`id`, ref, business_name, `usr`.`full_name`, date, `pmt`.`amount`, `pg`.`status` 
  FROM kv_ad_orders AS `pg` 
INNER JOIN kv_payments AS `pmt` ON `pg`.`ref` = `pmt`. `transId` 
LEFT JOIN kv_users AS `usr` ON `pg`.`sales_rep_id` = `usr`.`ID`
```

If all the data must match, go for this:

```
SELECT `pg`.`id`, ref, business_name, `usr`.`full_name`, date, `pmt`.`amount`, `pg`.`status` 
  FROM kv_ad_orders AS `pg` 
INNER JOIN kv_payments AS `pmt` ON `pg`.`ref` = `pmt`. `transId` 
INNER JOIN kv_users AS `usr` ON `pg`.`sales_rep_id` = `usr`.`ID`
```

If you are talking about query projection (columns to be returned regardless of the matching data) go for select pg.*

```
SELECT `pg`.*, `usr`.`full_name`, `pmt`.`amount`
  FROM kv_ad_orders AS `pg` 
LEFT JOIN kv_users AS `usr` ON `pg`.`sales_rep_id` = `usr`.`ID` 
RIGHT JOIN kv_payments AS `pmt` ON `pg`.`ref` = `pmt`. `transId`
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually i want the orders complete and payment and users are just picking one columns

Comment: If you are talking about query projection (not about matching rows) and want to show all the columns of `kv_ad_orders` go for `select `pg`.*`

Comment: Not that one. but i can get some idea from that., and i solved my issue. its necessary to use both at left join or right join.